# My vuejs code is infinite looping while in the production

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
       <template>
         <section class="speciality-area">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="row">
             <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 mt-2">
               <div class="archive-data-container" v-if="!listVisible && !paperPage"> 
                <div class="" v-for="year in years" :key="year">
                <h6>{{ year }}</h6>
                 <div class="row"  
                 v-for="(data, index) in archives[year]" :key="data.index">
                  <div class="col-lg-3 databox m-1 issueButton"   v-for="issue in data.sort()"
                    :key="issue.index"
                    @click="viewIssueData(year, index, issue)"> 
                    <p>Volume {{ index }} Issue {{ issue }}</p>
                  </div> 

                 </div>
               </div>
    
               </div>
           
             </div>
            
             <div class="paperlist-container " v-if="listVisible && !paperPage">
              <div class="row paperBox paperHeading mb-4 p-2 ">
                <h5 >{{ cYear }} | Volume {{ cVolume }} - Issue {{ cIssue }}</h5>
              </div>
              <div
                class="row paperBox mb-3"
                v-for="paper in papersList"
                :key="paper.paper_uniqueid"
              >
                <div class="col-9 p-3">
                  <h4>{{ paper.paper_title }}</h4>
                  <p><b>Author:</b> {{ paper.paper_author }}</p>
                  <p><b>Article Type:</b> {{ paper.paper_articletype }}</p>
                  <p><b>Pages:</b> {{ paper.paper_pages }}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3 p-3">
                  <b-button
                    class="col-8 mb-2"
                    variant="outline-primary"
                    size="sm"
                    @click="viewPaperDetails(paper.paper_id)"
                    >Paper Details</b-button
                  >
                  <b-button
                    class="col-8 mb-2"
                    variant="outline-primary"
                    size="sm"
                    @click="downloadPDF(paper.paper_url)"
                    >Download PDF</b-button
                  >
                  <b-button
                    class="col-8"
                    variant="outline-primary"
                    size="sm"
                    @click="googleSearch('https://www.google.com/search?q='+paper.paper_title)"
                    >Google</b-button
                  >
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="paperdetails-container" v-if="paperPage">
              <div class="row paperBox mb-4 p-3">
                <div class="header-container row justify-content-between rowSize">
                  <h4 class="col-10 pr-2">{{ paperDetails.paper_title }}</h4>
                  <div class="col-2" >
                    <b-button 
                      variant="outline-primary"
                      
                      @click="downloadPDF(paperDetails.paper_url)"
                      >Download PDF</b-button
                    >
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="details-container mt-4 p-3">
                  <!-- <div class="author-details pb-3"> -->
                    <p class="pb-3"><b>Author(s) : </b>{{ paperDetails.paper_author }}</p>
                  <!-- </div> -->
                  <!-- <div class="submit-details pb-3"> -->
              <p class="pb-3"><b>Submission-Year,Month : 
                 </b>{{ paperDetails.year }}, {{paperDetails.month }}</p> ` <
      !-- < /div> --> <
      !-- < div class = "author-details pb-3" > -->
      <
      p class = "pb-3" > < b > Pages: < /b>{{ paperDetails.paper_pages }}</p >
          <
          !-- < /div> --> <
          !-- < div class = "author-details pb-3" > -->
          <
          p class = "pb-3" > < b > Article Type: < /b>{{ paperDetails.paper_articletype }}</p >
          <
          !-- < /div> --> <
          !-- < div class = "author-details" > -->
          <
          p class = "pb-3" > < b > DOI: < /b>{{ paperDetails.paper_doi }}</p >
          <
          !-- < /div> --> <
          /div> <
          /div>  <
          div class = "row p-3 paperBox" >
          <
          h4 class = "mb-2" > Abstract < /h4> <
          p class = "abstract-details" > {
              {
                  paperDetails.paper_abstract
              }
          } <
          /p> <
          /div> <
          /div> <
          /div> <
          /div> <
          /div>

          <
          /section> <
          /template>

          <
          script >
          export default {
              data: function () {
                  return {
                      archives: {},
                      years: [],
                      papersList: [],
                      listVisible: false,
                      paperPage: false,
                      cYear: "",
                      cVolume: "",
                      cIssue: "",
                      paperDetails: {},
                  };
              },
              methods: {
                  getArchivesData: function () {
                      this.api.getDataModule("archives/3/getarchives", "journals/v1/").then(
                          (res) => {
                              console.log(res.data);
                              this.archives = res.data.archives;
                              this.sortData();
                          },
                          (err) => {
                              console.log(err);
                          }
                      );
                  },
                  getPapersList: function (year, volume, issue) {
                      this.api
                          .getDataModulePagination(
                              "archives/3/getpaperslist",
                              "journals/v1/",
                              "year=" + year + "&volume=" + volume + "&issue=" + issue
                          )
                          .then(
                              (res) => {
                                  this.papersList = res.data.papersList;
                              },
                              (err) => {
                                  console.log(err);
                              }
                          );
                  },
                  getPaperDetails: function (paperid) {
                      this.api
                          .getDataModulePagination(
                              "archives/3/getpaperdetails",
                              "journals/v1/",
                              "paperid=" + paperid
                          )
                          .then(
                              (res) => {
                                  this.paperDetails = res.data.paperdetails;
                              },
                              (err) => {
                                  console.log(err);
                              }
                          );
                  },
                  sortedIssues: function (val) {
                      return val.sort().reverse();
                  },
                  sortData: function () {
                      this.years = Object.keys(this.archives).sort().reverse();
                  },
                  viewIssueData: function (year, volume, issue) {
                      this.getPapersList(year, volume, issue);
                      this.cYear = year;
                      this.cVolume = volume;
                      this.cIssue = issue;
                      this.listVisible = true;
                      this.$router.push({
                          path: "archives",
                          query: {
                              year: year,
                              volume: volume,
                              issue: issue
                          },
                      });
                  },
                  viewPaperDetails: function (paperid) {
                      this.getPaperDetails(paperid);
                      this.paperPage = true;
                      this.$router.push({
                          path: "archives",
                          query: {
                              paperid: paperid
                          }
                      });
                  },
                  downloadPDF: function (paperURL) {
                      window.open(paperURL, "_blank");
                  },
                  googleSearch(url) {
                      window.open(url, "_blank");
                  },
              },
              watch: {
                  $route: function () {
                      console.log("here");
                      if (
                          !this.paperPage &&
                          this.listVisible &&
                          this.cYear == this.$route.query.year &&
                          this.cVolume == this.$route.query.volume &&
                          this.cIssue == this.$route.query.issue
                      ) {
                          this.listVisible = true;
                      } else {
                          this.listVisible = false;
                      }

                      if ("paperid" in this.$route.query) {
                          this.viewPaperDetails(this.$route.query.paperid);
                      } else {
                          this.paperPage = false;
                          this.getArchivesData();
                      }
                  },
              },
              mounted: function () {
                  if ("paperid" in this.$route.query) {
                      this.viewPaperDetails(this.$route.query.paperid);
                  } else {
                      this.listVisible = false;
                      this.paperPage = false;
                      this.getArchivesData();
                      console.log("thre");
                  }
              },
          }; <
      /script>

    Error: [Vue warn]: You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function.

    found in
 <ArchivesVue> at src/components/page_components/Archives/Archives.vue
```

Its perfectly running in the local host but in the production build its occuring infinite loop
I want to find out why the above code is infinite loop while on the production and I'm getting the waring also in the console. Need to fix this`. Just this was not working while on the production build need to rectify this. what changes need to do and why this was happening while on the production

Answer (score 0):

Upon component mount, you are invoking the **viewPaperDetails** method. Within this method, you are utilizing **$router.push**, which subsequently triggers the **route** watch method. However, inside the **route** watch, you are once again invoking the **viewPaperDetails** method. Consequently, this creates an infinite update loop within the component.